# Screen emulation is not available on this page

Tags: google-chrome

I just updated google-chrome-stable to version 32.0.1700.77 in my Ubuntu 13.04.

I tried to use this renamed feature, now called screen emulation, so I set the resolution to different values, but all I got was this message:

> screen emulation is not available on this page

I can't confirm if is it working for other OS/Chrome versions setup, but I'm pretty sure that it may be a problem with Google Chrome for Linux. Also I can't find discussion, blog post or even Chrome changelog.

Is it a bug or is it something in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On chrome://flags I enabled the "Override software rendering list" option, which solved the issue.

Comment: Hey @Wouter this did the trick. I don't quite understand why this is an experimental on linux, should I be worried about activated this feature?

Comment: Well, having it on doesn't work perfectly for me. When I turn it on, my browser doesn't trigger on any hover effects any more. Acceptable for mobile testing, but very annoying on desktop view.

That's probably a reason why it's experimental.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 34.0.1847.116 chrome://flags "Override software rendering list" didn't work for me, I've had to disable "GPU compositing on all pages"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 12.04. But enabling "Override software rendering list" option did not work for me. I checked current chrome version `Version 32.0.1700.102` and then I updated chrome to `Version 32.0.1700.107` and it started working.